# How to check csv file type in c#

Tags: c#

I am checking the csv extension as below:

```
   string extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(UploadFile.PostedFile.FileName);
      //check file extension
   if (!(extension == ".csv"))
    {
    }
```

should i need to check for the .CSV too?
like:

```
 if (!(extension == ".csv" || extension ==".CSV"))
```

Comment: `if (!extension.ToLower() == ".csv")`

Answer (score 0):

Extension can be null, so I'd used something like `".csv".Equals(extension, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`